# import .sql files into mysql from batch file

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file, import

Hello im creating a batch file to install the wampserver . After that i want to import my name.sql file into the dabase  that wampserver created. Im using this command :

```
mysql --u [bonis] --password=[bonis] ["jdbc:mysql://localhost"] < ["C:\Documents and    Settings\Bonis\Desktop\bpx.sql"]

pause
```

And telling me this : "The filename, directoryname, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command line: mysql < name.sql

Your sql code in the file has to contain "create database" and "create table" commands, though.